# Can we create a shape in the word document without relying on paragraphs using apache poi?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I have read some articles on how to draw shapes on word document using VML. But in order to create those shapes, we must create a paragraph either in the header, body or the footer of the document and assign a shape to paragraph. I want to know is there any way we can create a shape in word document without relying on paragraphs?

Any inputs or references would be much appreciated.